# Keycloak - Client Roles - Retrieve custom attributes

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-javascript

I have created a client role as `special_agent` and have added two attributes as `approve_leave` and `raise_leave`.

[image: Keycloak - Client Role Attributes]

I'm using the [Javascript adapter](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.adoc) and am able to login successfully on my website. I'm also able to receive the client role that I have assigned to the user. I, however, want to get the custom attributes specified in the client role. Below is the result of the keycloak.tokenParsed

[image: Keycloak - tokenParsed]

Is there a way to retrieve client role attributes? I looked for the `Mappers` in the Client settings, but couldn't figure out the details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the Client's role and attribute by API call.
GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}

Example for)

[image]

There are a couple of requirements.
#1 User(agency_user) should assigned two roles(manage-realm, view-clients) in Keyclaok UI
[image]

#2 get access token by API and save into Postman variable
http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token
Client id & secret get from Keyclaok UI as attached
[image]
[image]
[image]

#3 You should know the client ID by GET client API using #1 access token
http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/test/clients
[image]

More detail information, Good Luck!
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_roles_resource

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Script Mapper, e.g.,

```
var roles = {}
for each (var role in user.getRoleMappings()) {
    roles[role.name] = role.getAttributes();
}
token.setOtherClaims('roles', roles);
```